# MODIS Quality Control in QGIS

Tags: qgis, modis, data-quality, lai

I have to process 46 MODIS MOD15A2H images (leaf area index) in QGIS 2.12 Lyon. I have to clean the images from bad pixels using MODIS Quality Control. Is there any method to automate the process for this amount of images?

Comment: hi did you find answer to your question? Can you contribute

Comment: Hi, in the end I managed to do it through MODIS dedicated software MRT (modis reprojection tool), but on the basis of what I see on NASA website, it has been retired: https://lpdaac.usgs.gov/news/downloadable-modis-reprojection-tool-mrt-and-mrtswath-tool-have-been-retired/